# ParticleSystem issue with enableEmission

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system

that's my very first question in here (not a first visit searching solution, though ;D).

I've got an issue with ParticleSystem in Unity:

```
    if (!dead) {
        dieBang.enableEmission = false;
        Vector2 newVelocity = rigidbody2D.velocity;
        newVelocity.x = forwardMovementSpeed;
        rigidbody2D.velocity = newVelocity;
    } else
        dieBang.enableEmission = true;
    UpdateGroundedStatus ();
```

The problem is `dieBang.enableEmmision` gets `true` only when `dead` state is caused by on object(laser) I manually "put" in the game. When character hits laser generated of prefab, it gets dead, stop moving etc. , but there is no `dieBang` :D
Hope you can help me

Comment: Side note: please make sure tags added to your posts are reasonable - i.e. "unity" is for DI injection framework, "unity3d" is for game engine framework. I've re-tagged this question as it is unlikely related to DI.

Comment: Where do you instantiate the particles gameobject?

Comment: @LokiSinclair , I declared it : `public ParticleSystem dieBang;`

Comment: Declared and dragged in via the editor, yes? In which case, you'll still need to instantiate(dieBang, someGameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) - When you want to see it. Otherwise, it'll play once and then be destroyed. Any NullReferenceExceptions will be displayed in the Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say with the limited info here but I have a hunch that your particle system is being destroyed with the character so you will never see the particle effect.

Either destroy the character after the effect is complete or instantiate the particle system without a parent so it isn't destroyed by accident.

EDIT: Also worth noting, if you're simply disabling the character when it's hit instead of destroying the game object, you'll have the same effect because the parent is disabled, thus disabling the children(ie. the particle system).

Comment: I don't destroy the character, when it dies, actually. It just stops and falls to the ground.

Comment: Hmm... Try this:

dieBang.enableEmission = true;

dieBang.Play();

Comment: It helped, `dieBang` started emmision after hiting prefab-laser. But, I set it not to loop, to make just one "bang". Now it's looped. I guess it's because `dieBang.Play()` is inside `Fixed Update`, so the `dieBang.Play()` method is called continously? Is there a way to play it just once? I'm really a newbie (3 days) with Unity, I'm learning with tutorial , and tried to apply some modifications of my own ;p

Comment: There are a number of ways to structure your code. Based on what I've seen, I would move the `dieBang.enableEmission = true` and `dieBang.Play()` in the same function that changes `dead` to `true`